# Fitch Question, Please help!

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

Q ∧ S

(Q ∧ ¬P) → ¬R

Q → ¬P

(S ∧ T) → (P ∨ R)

The goal is:¬T

Answer (score 1):

Derive a contradiction under the assumption of `T`, so that you may deduce `¬T` by negation introduction.

```
|  Q ∧ S
|  (Q ∧ ¬P) → ¬R
|  Q → ¬P
|_ (S ∧ T) → (P ∨ R)
|  S                    ∧ E
|  Q                    ∧ E
:  :
|  |_ T
|  |  S ∧ T             ∧ I 
|  |  P ∨ R             → E
:  :  :
|  |  #
|  ¬T                   ¬ I
```